# How to make a select list modify a property in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of devices, with each device containing actions. I am using nested ng-repeats to list out all the devices and provide a select list containing all the actions. How can I go about creating a property on the device that will always represent the currently selected action? Here is the code I have currently:

```
  <div class="span5 outputDevices well" droppable>
    Drag a device here for output

    <div class="droppedDevice" ng-repeat="outputDevice in outputDevices" >
      <h1>{{outputDevice.fields.baseDevice.fields.name}}</h1>

      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeDevice('output', $index)">
          X
      </button>

      <select class="outputActions">
        <option>
          Select Action
        </option>
        <option ng-repeat="action in outputDevice.fields.baseDevice.fields.outputs">
          {{action.fields.name}}
        </option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT:** I have tried modifying my select as per the comment below, however the actions do not seem to be repeating at all now:

```
      <select class="inputActions" ng-options="action.fields.name for action in inputDevice.fields.baseDevice.fields.inputs">
        <option value="">
          Select Action
        </option>
      </select>
```

Comment: You may consider using select and ngOptions directives together, instead of ngRepeat [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)

Comment: Can you post your app code too? Maybe in a fiddle/plunker demo.

Comment: "action in outputDevice..." in original code, but "action in inputDevice..." in modified code, you might want to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `ngModel` directive on the `select`, as:

```
<select class="outputActions" ng-model="outputDevice.action"
        ng-options="action.fields.name for action in outputDevice.fields.baseDevice.fields.inputs">
    <option value="">
      Select Action
    </option>
</select>
```

In this way, if an action is selected, `outputDevice.action` will be set to the selected action.